# Docker - increase size of the /dev/shm

Tags: docker, sedna

To run Sedna XML database I need to increase size of the `/dev/shm`. It's now 64M.

Is there some easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case somebody stumbles upon this - it is now available as a CLI option to 'docker run':

```
  --shm-size                      Size of /dev/shm, default value is 64MB
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like it is no possible for now, the shared memory size is currently hardcoded to 64M.

Several people have expressed interest in the same feature, and it is being worked on, [check this Github issue](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/pull/4981).